# errors separated from list not working

Tags: python

i got this part of my code that is causing me problem. First, this part of the software will take the function, it will test it and may display errors depending on the file i opened earlier.

If i print(I) where it is right now, itll print the list and the error. I've tried multiple way to set it after the error with while true and if but never worked.

Thanks here's the part of the code.

```
if texte in choix:
    message = sorted(ligne(texte))
    for i in message:
        parts = i.split(":")
        gauche = parts[0].strip()
        droite = parts[1]
        try:
            droite = int(droite)
            print(i)
        except ValueError:
            print("La ligne '", i, "' n'est pas correctement formaté.")
            sys.exit()
        if not gauche.isalpha():
            print("La ligne '", i, "' n'est pas correctement formaté.")
            sys.exit()
    break

else:
    print("Il faut préciser le nom du fichier à traiter")
    break
```

Exemple of a list:
    pommes : 54
    bananes : 18
    oranges : 30

```
ananas :12
clémentines    :77
cerises de terre:    43
```

Kind of result i recieve is

```
ananas :  12
bananes :  18
cerises de terre :  43
La ligne ' cerises de terre : 43 ' n'est pas correctement formaté.
```

I only want

```
La ligne ' cerises de terre : 43 ' n'est pas correctement formaté.
```

Comment: Accurate indentation is very important in Python code. Perhaps you would like to [fix](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43500110/edit) your indentation so this code makes sense.

Comment: Can you also post the exact error message your receive?

Comment: sorry i fixed it...the copy paste went bad. The code is barely working fine, but it just display the list when its supose to only display the error. The error are in ValueError: I've updated my code so you can see the input i want.

Comment: Just remove `print(i)` in the `try` block...

Comment: @Isen I don't see any lists displayed.

Comment: sorry i updated it.

Comment: roganjosh i need the print(i) in the for because i is each line of a list. If i remove it itll just print the first line.

Comment: It's possible for you to pass the `try`/`except` and still fail on the second check. Both give the same error message. Add "because the left hand side failed validation" and "because the right hand side failed validation" and then you will understand what's actually going on.

Comment: i totaly understand that logic and this logic is explained well in the post under this. It didn't work. for whatever reason. what should i do to encapsulate this thing to run before the passed code after the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
if texte in choix:
    message = sorted(ligne(texte))
    for i in message:
        parts = i.split(":")
        gauche = parts[0].strip()
        droite = parts[1]
        try:
            droite = int(droite)
            if not gauche.isalpha():
                print("La ligne '", i, "' n'est pas correctement formaté.")
                sys.exit()
        except ValueError:
            print("La ligne '", i, "' n'est pas correctement formaté.")
            sys.exit()
        print(i)
    break

else:
    print("Il faut préciser le nom du fichier à traiter")
    break
```

However if you just want the error printed remove that `print(i)`

Comment: I'm assuming part of the confusion here is that the error message for ther exception and the `if not gauche.isalpha():` is identical. That's not particularly helpful for debugging.

Comment: I totally agree, but frankly didn't want to go into details :)

Comment: because im testing the left and the right expression. Both of them not only 1. It also didnt work since im still recieving the list in the output with the error. The thing is i need the error to be treated in the for and the print too but i need to excluse the print if the error happen.

Comment: @Isen because you are printing _`i`_ which is prior to the split. Both failure routes end up with exactly the same error message.

Comment: @Isen I edited code and it is very ugly but it should match your needs.

Comment: when is my list supose to be printed into your code? i need to display the list in the for somewhere if there are no error.

Comment: @Isen You explicitly said you only want error message. Now it prints i. Lovely :)

Comment: When i print  your solution its giving me the same result. I still see my 2 first item and then the error. again if it remove print(I) everything works fine. So there'S something more to do with it i cant find.

Comment: is there a way we could make that the list is read completly and only return error and then it read it agian and return the right thing